# Postgresql catch rollback when function fails on one of multiple inserts but trigger was executed

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, rollback

I've got plpgsql function that does multiple inserts to multiple tables. 
I've also trigger that do some stuff f.g notifies some service.

The process looks like this:

1. Insert into table A
2. Trigger executed on table A
3. Function fails on
   insert into table B

And then transaction is rollbacked and I've got no data in table A but trigger has executed. 
Furthemore there is no any DELETE on table A.

My trigger and function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_function() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify('pgchannel1', row_to_json(new)::text);
    RETURN NULL;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER some_trigger
    AFTER INSERT
    ON some_table
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE some_function();
```

I would like to have this process like that:

1. Insert into table A
2. Insert into table B
3. Trigger executed on table A / Trigger executed when function is done

How could I catch that transaction was rollbacked and not executing trigger?
Is there any way to trigger function status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with *constraint triggers*:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER some_trigger
   AFTER INSERT ON some_table
   DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE some_function();
```

Such a trigger will fire at the end of the transaction rather than immediately.

Comment: Thats it. 
There is another question. Is it possible to spy function state or trigger after its execution (done).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: I've got function that is executing multiple inserts on multiple tables. Is there any way to trigger function when it finish?

Comment: No, a trigger is always defined on one table.